# Delete from Multiple Checkbox process error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a million rows of data, but does not have different data on the primary key and I want to delete multiple rows from check-box form with the multiple columns but it failed.

If I try to use as insert to database it is working.

Following is the error detail:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( "71", "03", "090", "005", "001", ' at line 13

#### HTML Code

```html
 <input type="hidden" name="bayar[NM_WP_SPPT][]" value="<?=$NM_WP_SPPT?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_PROPINSI][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_PROPINSI']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_DATI2][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_DATI2']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_KECAMATAN][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_KECAMATAN']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_KELURAHAN][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_KELURAHAN']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_BLOK][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_BLOK']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[NO_URUT][]" value="<?=$itung['NO_URUT']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_JNS_OP][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_JNS_OP']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[THN_PAJAK_SPPT][]" value="<?=$tahun?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[TGL_JATUH_TEMPO_SPPT][]" value="<?=$itung['TGL_JATUH_TEMPO_SPPT']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[PEMBAYARAN_SPPT_KE][]" value="<?=$itung['PEMBAYARAN_SPPT_KE']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_KANWIL_BANK][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_KANWIL_BANK']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_KPPBB_BANK][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_KPPBB_BANK']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_BANK_TUNGGAL][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_BANK_TUNGGAL']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_BANK_PERSEPSI][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_BANK_PERSEPSI']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[KD_TP][]" value="<?=$itung['KD_TP']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[DENDA_SPPT][]" value="<?=$jumlah_tunggakan?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[SEJUMLAH_RP][]" value="<?=$jumlah_yg_harus_dibayar?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[JML_SPPT_YG_DIBAYAR][]" value="<?=$itung['PBB_YG_HARUS_DIBAYAR_SPPT']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[TGL_PEMBAYARAN_SPPT][]" value="<?=date('Y-m-d', time())?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[TGL_REKAM_BYR_SPPT][]" value="<?=date('Y-m-d', time())?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="bayar[NIP_REKAM_BYR_SPPT][]" value="<?="060000000"?>">
```

#### Code to delete from database

```
$values = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['bayar']['THN_PAJAK_SPPT']); $i++) {
  $values[] = '(
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_PROPINSI'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_DATI2'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_KECAMATAN'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_KELURAHAN'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_BLOK'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['NO_URUT'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_JNS_OP'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['THN_PAJAK_SPPT'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['PEMBAYARAN_SPPT_KE'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_KANWIL_BANK'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_KPPBB_BANK'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_BANK_TUNGGAL'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_BANK_PERSEPSI'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['KD_TP'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['DENDA_SPPT'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['JML_SPPT_YG_DIBAYAR'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['TGL_PEMBAYARAN_SPPT'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['TGL_REKAM_BYR_SPPT'][$i].'",
    "'.$_POST['bayar']['NIP_REKAM_BYR_SPPT'][$i].'"
  )';
}


$delete = "DELETE FROM PEMBAYARAN_TES WHERE (KD_PROPINSI , KD_DATI2 , KD_KECAMATAN , KD_KELURAHAN , KD_BLOK , NO_URUT , KD_JNS_OP ,
                THN_PAJAK_SPPT , PEMBAYARAN_SPPT_KE , KD_KANWIL_BANK , KD_KPPBB_BANK , KD_BANK_TUNGGAL , KD_BANK_PERSEPSI , KD_TP ,
              DENDA_SPPT , JML_SPPT_YG_DIBAYAR , TGL_PEMBAYARAN_SPPT , TGL_REKAM_BYR_SPPT , NIP_REKAM_BYR_STTS) = " . implode(',', $values);

mysqli_query($conn, $delete) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

What does the error mean? and how to solve it?

If the 'delete query' cannot be like that, what is the other way to delete multiple rows from check-boxes with `'where multiple column name'`?

Comment: Post the entire sql statement. Alternatively, capture it and attempt to execute it directly vis-à-vis your DB.

Answer (score 0):

HTML checkbox form element returns 'on' if checked, and returns nothing if unckecked. So, to see if checkbox was checked you have to use isset() command (if you know in advance what checkbox should/should not come) and check database column correspondingly. Here you receive only checked checkboxes and set where clause for them. If you need to set IS NOT for unchecked checkbxes then you have to list them in advance.

```
$where=[];
$bayars=$_POST['bayar'];//gets 2D array
foreach($bayars as $midbayars)
{
  foreach($midbayars as $key=>$bayar)
  {
    $where[]=$key.'='.1; //or whatewer is in database
  }
}

$SQL='DELETE FROM PEMBAYARAN_TES WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$where)
```